# File Read, printing on a single line

Tags: java

Why does it print the file it reads on a single line? The txt file is not.

The file is like this:

---

Student N. 3
ID: 999
Surname: Spider
Name: Man

### ******************

### Subject N. 1 : d. Chart Reading

Homework 1: 89

Homework 2: 65

Homework 3: 32

Exam 1: 45

Exam 2: 56

Exam 3: 78

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner data = new Scanner(new FileReader("StudData1.txt"));

    while(data.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.print(data.nextLine());
    }
```

Comment: Either `System.out.print(data.nextLine() + "\n");` or `System.out.println(data.nextLine());`.

Comment: change  System.out.print to  System.out.println

Comment: Thanks! Was pretty simple... Should have guessed it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `System.out.print()` to `System.out.println()` if you want to print in different line.

You should know the difference between these two. Follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) link.